# how to render datetime in a particular format in extjs

Tags: date, extjs, render

I have a grid in there is field updatedon which is datetime coming from db 
e.g. 2011-03-22 01:45:00

here is my reader code :

```
{name: 'updatedon', type:'datetime'},
```

here is my renderer code :

```
{
    id       :'updatedon',
    header   : ' updatedon', 
    width    : 100, 
    sortable : true, 
    dataIndex: 'updatedon',
    renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y')
},
```

how should i render to get 22/03/2011

Answer (score 5, accepted):

done by changing the reader code

```
{name: 'updatedon' ,type:'date' ,dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'},
```